# called id for nil, which would mistakenly be 4 for form_for . why it is always 4 for nil?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

When I use rails form_for

```
form_for @users do |f|
end
```

Why does it say that nil has a value of 4?

Comment: Could you provide a citation for exactly what is saying "4 for nil"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This might help you . Its because the object id for nil is 4.

http://blog.bigbinary.com/2008/06/23/why-the-id-of-nil-is-4-in-ruby.html

Answer (score 0):

Check this at console,

```
nil.object_id # => 4
```

So here it looks like **@users** object is nil.